# How to use the expression "throw oneself into something"

Tags: idioms, usage, expressions

I have recently learned the expression "throw oneself into something", but I am kind of confused about how to use it in daily conversation. Could anyone explain me this, with some examples?

For example,

> I've thrown myself into learning English.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? If yes, then what does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "to throw oneself into" is a standard idiom.

- [cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throw-yourself-into-sth): to do something ​actively and ​enthusiastically
- [thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+oneself+into): to enter into or join something eagerly and wholeheartedly
- [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/throw--oneself--into): to engage in with energy or enthusiasm (definition 53)
- [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/throw-oneself-into): start to do (something) with enthusiasm and vigour

Answer (score 1):

To

> throw *oneself* into *something*

is to work on or study or become involved in *something* without holding back or reservation.

> I've thrown myself into the deep end *( of the pool )*

is a possible metaphor (unless you really did go into the deep end of a pool) to say your situation is all or nothing, sink or swim.

Comment: Can you give me some more examples of this idiom on how to use it daily conversation

Comment: "He's so excited about his new hobby, he's completely thrown himself into it and ignores everything else." "She's thrown herself into her new relationship without really thinking about it." "The kids have thrown themselves into this new video game and won't stop playing it."

Comment: hi Peter ,I see that in your example if the subject is singular (like he and she ) you have used the "apostrophe s ( 's ) " and if the subject is plural ( like kids ) you have used " have " 
So by this I should consider using apostrophe s for singular and have for plural .Right?

Comment: he's = he has, she's = she has.  "I **have** thrown myself into following March Madness". The use of **to have** follows the number of the subject.

Comment: Thanks a ton Peter your explanation really cleared my doubts I really appreciate your efforts and thanks to all of you who answered my question.